# Set a DEFAULT value to DATE SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to set a DEFAULT DATE to a column, but it needs to be an arbitrary date that I choose lets say 2011-30-11. What is the ALTER TABLE command I need to run to achieve this

ALTER TABLE table
CHANGE COLUM column1 DATE DEFAULT _______

What do i need?
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Column has an `N` in it: `ALTER TABLE table CHANGE COLUMN column1 DATE`, then `SET DEFAULT '2011-11-30'`?

Comment: Thank you. I found an alternative before seeing your comment. This works too

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT  '2018-xx-xx'`. Where xx is the month and day of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE `table1` 
ADD COLUMN `date1` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01';

Comment: That adds a column, you asked about changing a column.